gcc-14.2.0/ld cannot find -lstdc++
I am trying to build native gcc-14.2.0 from sources by this tutorial - https://gist.github.com/chponte/7f27967fc72cf61e8c158923bf126b61
I am doing it on hyper-v with OS Astra Linux with installed gcc.
When I try to build glibc with
CC=/tmp/gcc-first-stage/bin/gcc ../glibc-x.x/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix=$PREFIX --with-headers=${TARGET_PREFIX}/include --without-selinux
make all install

I get the following error:

/home/elena/gcc2/14.2.0/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory

I had tried all, which is suggested in this article - https://hatchjs.com/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc-no-such-file-or-directory/ , but nothing works.
Also I have tried to put libstdc++.so to /home/elena/gcc2/14.2.0/bin  and this did not help me too.
What else could be the reason for this error?
UPDATE 1: libstdc++.so in my system located in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so
UPDATE 2: this does not help too - "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory" on running flutter linux app
UPDATE 3:

make  subdir=mathvec -C mathvec ..=../ others make  subdir=support -C
support ..=../ others make[2]: вход в каталог
«/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-2.39/support»
/tmp/gcc-first-stage/bin/gcc
-Wl,-rpath-link=/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/math:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/elf:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/dlfcn:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/nss:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/nis:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/rt:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/resolv:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/mathvec:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/support:/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/nptl
-o /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/support/links-dso-program
-pie -Wl,-z,pack-relative-relocs -Wl,-O1 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -Wl,-z,mark-plt   -Wl,-z,relro  /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/csu/Scrt1.o
/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/csu/crti.o
/tmp/gcc-first-stage/bin/gcc -Wl,-z,mark-plt --print-file-name=crtbeginS.o /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/support/links-dso-program.o
-lstdc++ -lgcc -lgcc_s  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/elena/gcc2/14.2.0/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/libc.so.6
/home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a
-Wl,--as-needed /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/elf/ld.so
-Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  /tmp/gcc-first-stage/bin/gcc -Wl,-z,mark-plt --print-file-name=crtendS.o /home/elena/Desktops/Desktop1/gcc-build-root-2/glibc-build/csu/crtn.o
/home/elena/gcc2/14.2.0/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: Нет такого файла
или каталога collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом
возврата 1


@9769953 usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so

That second article should be taken with a few grains of salt: it mentions setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and adjusting ld.so.conf, both of which are you used for running a program (the loader), not when building a program (the linker). It also feels very woolly: lot of text repeating itself; hard to tell if it's  AI generated or a human write-up (or a combination).

@9769953 Thanks for your answer. Slash at the start is not missing, when I run in terminal command g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.so. I missed the slash here by mistake...

@9769953 where should I put path to the libstdc++, so that it be used for building a program (the linker)?

I'm a bit surprised the linker wants to link libstdc++, while everything in your question is about building (just) gcc.

I am trying to build glibc now. First stage of building gcc (before building glibc in tutorial) is already passed.  And for building glibc tutorial says to use 'make all install'

@9769953 Please see screenshot in the 3rd update of question

@9769953 Thanks, fixed it - replaced screenshot by quote

Here are a few suggestions that may let the linker (ld) find the missing library. Try them in order. Be aware that while this may let the linker proceed, you could run into other issues later (which may or may not be related to the stdlibc++ library).

First, try with LIBRARY_PATH. I've never used it, but the gcc manual suggests this is exactly for finding paths to libraries. Set it as an environment variable (env-var) before running make, thus

export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/

and then run the make command again.

If that didn't work, try with good ol' LDFLAGS, which is a more general-purpose env-var for setting various flags in the linker stage.

export LDFLAGS='-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/'

and run make again.

Double check that the loader can find this library for when you are running a program. It should, since it's a library installed by the system, but just in case. You can look in /etc/ld.so.conf and all the files in the related subdirectory, /etc/ld.so.conf.d. Since these should all be text files, a simple
cat /etc/ld.so.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*

should be enough. See if any (non-commented, obviously) line is equal to /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8.

This answer is the more generic answer. The idea of requiring libstdc++ for a build of glibc doesn't sit nice with me, and I feel that the actual guide you're following misses something somewhere. The thing is also, sometimes gcc means the GNU C compiler, and sometimes it's the whole GNU compiler suite, which includes g++ (and at times, gfortran). There is of course the flag --enable-languages=c,c++ in stage 2, but why then build glibc and not libstdc++ as well? And why does glibc require libstdc++?

Thanks a lot! export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/  helps me. glibc build is passed...

Nice. I learned something new, because LIBRARY_PATH is not something I've used before. Might be a gcc-only thing, don't know (LDFLAGS is more generally used).

@9769953 told ya, my question was gonna get closed haha!

@9769953 You caught me, I have reopened it.
